# baton.notifyAll gives java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException despite synchronized(baton)

Tags: java, multithreading

I am new to multi threading and sorry for small question. I could not find what is wrong in below code. I am getting

```
0-Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
```

**What I'm trying to achieve**

I am trying to create an array of worker threads, each of which will print the value that is set for that particular `Thread` object. I want the threads to wait for their turn to come and then they will execute the code and update value of `baton` (I suspect I am doing this wrong) before notifying the other threads, so that the next thread in the cycle will then repeat the process.

Here is my code. Thanks!

```
package test;

public class NThread
{
  public static Integer baton;

  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
  {
    baton = 0;
    TestUtil.N = 2;
    runThread();
  }

  protected static void runThread() throws InterruptedException
  {
    int i;
    ThreadB b[] = new ThreadB[TestUtil.N];
    for (i = 0; i < TestUtil.N; i++)
    {
      b[i] = new ThreadB();
      b[i].val = i;
      b[i].start();
    }
  }
}

class ThreadB extends Thread
{
  public int val;

  @Override
  public void run()
  {
    synchronized (NThread.baton)
    {
      while (true)
      {
        if (NThread.baton != val)
        {
          try
          {
            NThread.baton.wait();
          }
          catch (InterruptedException e)
          {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
        }
        else
        {
          TestUtil.printNum(val);
          NThread.baton = (NThread.baton+1) % TestUtil.N;
          NThread.baton.notifyAll();
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That is _not_ the full stack trace. Please post the whole error, and it would be helpful if you indicated which line is problematic.

Comment: As a side note, your main function is spawning multiple threads in runThread(), but is not waiting for them to complete. It may exit before the threads complete their processing. You should wait for them using Thread.join() for each thread.

Comment: @NicolasRiousset. To be clear: the main function may exit, but the program won't stop running as the threads are not daemon threads.

Comment: @amit_yo I would also recommend you read the answers to [Hello World with Multithreading Java](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32295467/1945631) which is a very similar program and solution to yours. One answer shows a 2-ary "baton" and the other shows an alternative solution to your exact scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do `synchronized (NThread.baton)`, but then inside that synchronized section you change the `baton` object reference using `NThread.baton = (NThread.baton+1) % TestUtil.N;`. As you now have a new object reference in `baton` you are no longer locking on it, so when you next call `baton.notifyAll()` it is on an object you haven't synchronized on - hence your `IllegalMonitorStateException`.

To fix this you need to split out your synchronization object (and make it immutable using `final` - which is always a good rule anyway) from your trigger (your `baton`). i.e. have a single `static final Object monitor = new Object();` which you synchronize, wait and notify on, and keep `baton` for your numeric trigger.

A lightly updated sample is:

```
class ThreadB implements Runnable {
    public final int val;
    public ThreadB(int val) { this.val = val; }

    @Override public void run() {
        try {
            //  synchronize outside the loop so we don't constantly lock/unlock
            synchronized (NThread.monitor) {
                while (true) { // spin until interrupted
                    while (NThread.baton != val) // handle spurious wake-ups
                        NThread.monitor.wait();
                    //  print, increment and notify
                    TestUtil.printNum(val);
                    NThread.baton = (NThread.baton + 1) % TestUtil.N;
                    NThread.monitor.notifyAll();
                }
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // if interrupted then we exit
        }
    }
}
```

run using:

```
public class NThread {
    public static int baton;
    public static final Object monitor = new Object();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        baton = 0;
        TestUtil.N = 2;
        runThread();
    }

    protected static void runThread() throws InterruptedException {
        int i;
        Thread b[] = new Thread[TestUtil.N];
        for (i = 0; i < b.length; i++) { // loop limit is on the array length - its clearer like that
            b[i] = new Thread(new ThreadB(i));
            b[i].start();
        }
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
        for (i = 0; i < b.length; i++) b[i].interrupt();
        for (i = 0; i < b.length; i++) b[i].join();
        System.out.println("All done");
    }
}
```

This would usually undergo a lot more refactoring, such as injecting the common monitor, baton and number of participants into the Runnable's constructor to prevent making those fields public (usually using some kind of custom class to contain them all). I didn't go that far so you could see the link to your original code.

*As a separate footnote, it is also better practice not to override `Thread` and `run`, but instead to split out your actions from the threading objects, and so make `ThreadB` implement `Runnable`, which you then provide to the constructor of a `Thread`.*

Comment: I was able to do what I wanted to achieve in first place without using the for loops for join and interrupt. I will need to read more on that. I would be missing something.

Comment: @amit_yo. You probably aren't missing anything - I just added those lines to show you how to cleanly shutdown your threads and wait on them to complete.

Answer (score 1):

You have to understand that `synchronized` does not apply a lock to the *field* you are storing a value in, but on the object that is stored in that field.

To execute `wait` or `notifyAll` you are required to have monitor lock on the object you are executing this for. I think you noticed that problem, because you are using the boxing class `Integer` instead of a `int` for the field. You did this because `synchronized` did complain that it can't lock on a value type. During the incrementation a new boxing object is created. And this new object is not any longer covered by the `synchronized` block.

In your case I think the best solution is to use a utility object that you can use for locking. Any simple instance of `Object` will do.